# Converting Access 2.0 to Access 95 Constant Crash

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2000

I've been given the inglorious task of converting a Access 2.0 database to work on Access 2010...

I have a copy of Access 95 to help make the jump (I can't find a copy of Access 97).  I also have Access 2000, 2007 and 2013.  I'm doing this on an XP machine.

I create a new Access 95 .mdb, then import the Access 2.0 Tables, Queries, then Forms... every time I import a form it only remembers the first form.  If I try to import more than one form, it crashes after importing only 2.

I've tried all sorts of saving/resaving/importing permutations, but no luck.

Any ideas?

Thanks a million, 
Scott

Comment: Sounds like this should have been done 15 - 20 years ago :)

Comment: And how useful is that statement for Scott?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Access 2000. It will read Access 2.0 files and code.

The 2000-version database you can then read directly from Access 2010/2013 and convert. So it is a two-step process.

I haven't tried with Access 2016 but it should work as well.

You will need to adjust API calls but otherwise the necessary code changes are remarkable few. That said, you will probably wish to brush up and optimise the code, and that can be a major task.